# How do you change the font face Sublime uses for the sidebar?

Tags: fonts, sublimetext2, customization, monospace

Is this even possible in Sublime Text 2?

Since the default preferences says:

`// The theme controls the look of Sublime Text's UI (buttons, tabs, scroll bars, etc)
"theme": "Default.sublime-theme",`

I tried modifying that file

(under `/Data/Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme`)

by adding this line:

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_label"
    , "color": [0, 0, 0]
    , "font.bold": false
    , "shadow_color": [250, 250, 250], "shadow_offset": [0, 0]
    , "font.face": "monospace" // ADDED THIS LINE ("monofur" is the monospace font I use in the editor window itself)
}
```

But that simply causes all file and folder names in the sidebar to become *blank*.

Changing the other line to `"font.bold" = true` *does* cause all the names to become bold, so... ?????

Comment: Did you add all those lines, or did you add `"font.face" to an already-existing class? If you added a new class, you probably screwed something up.

Comment: I only added the line that says "// ADDED THIS LINE".

Comment: Did you try any other fonts? Also, I've found that you have to restart ST2 in order for everything to look right.

Comment: Yes to both, but actually, I just got it to work, apparently by first messing around with some settings in other parts of the theme first? I noticed that a setting I added had an effect, then didn't change back when I removed it, and only changed back when I added it again with a different value, so... "something was stuck"? xD Dunno, duncare, worksnao. MAGIC!

Comment: well, if you can figure out what you did, feel free to write it up as an answer to help others...

Comment: Yeah, of course I would. I just have no idea what I did. xD It seems like it was a pretty weird, idiosyncratic bug. If someone *does* happen across this post and has the same problem, just ask in a comment, and I'll try to untangle my edit history...

Comment: I found switching to a different theme by editing the user prefs file (Preferences -> Settings - User) and then switching back made font changes work for me. Before I did that, changing the `font.face` property made the sidebar font labels disappear...