# Change the font_face of the sidebar in Sublime Text 2

Tags: fonts, themes, sidebar

I can change the font_size of the Sidebar of Sublime Text 2. I do this in "class": "sidebar_label", The font "font_face": "Ubuntu Mono", I can't set. Is this a restriction of Sublime 2?

[Sublime Text 2 how to change the font size of the file sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781833/sublime-text-2-how-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-file-sidebar)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Mark

Comment: Even tried font.face too.

Comment: I also tried answers of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337160/how-do-you-change-the-font-face-sublime-uses-for-the-sidebar

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. The font wouldn't change until I used: "font.size": 14,

Comment: Would you please elaborate so others can use this answer too?